# Is "could" the past form of "can"?

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs

I'm kind of confused by what our teacher taught us today. He specifically said that "could" is the past form of "can", and the same for "shall" and "will". I also recall that he gave as this example:

*"That kid **could** produce a few words when he was 2."* – to mean *"That kid **was able** to produce a few words when he was 2."*

I only know that could is more polite (when it comes to permission) but is that a valid sentence?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your teacher is quite correct: *could, might, should, would* are the 'past' forms of *can, may, shall, will*. The example your teacher gave you is perfectly OK; you would also use these forms to backshift present-tense forms in reported speech:

> "I **can** bench-press three hundred pounds", says John.
>   John **said** that he **could** bench-press three hundred pounds.

*Must* has no distinct 'past' form; historically, however, it **is** the 'past' form of a verb which has lost its present form, *mote*.

And that's a process that's still going on today. *Shall* has almost disappeared from Present-Day English, except in legal contexts, and *may* is in steep decline. *Must* is very little used now as a past-tense form; some teachers even tell their students that *had to* must be used instead. Similarly, past-tense *could* and *would* are giving way to *was/were able to* and *was/were going to*.

I suspect that what underlies these usage shifts is that the so-called 'past' forms of verbs don't always signify backshift—past-tense reference—but are also used to signify what we might call 'sideshift': a  less assertive social or logical modality. This is especially true with the core modal verbs, which are the primary indicators of modality; the 'past' forms of these verbs are used so frequently to signal social or logical distance that the use for actual past-tense reference has become secondary. Except in the most formal registers, *could, might, should, would* have become almost (but not quite) disconnected from their present-tense forms.

Comment: +1 for mote, as it's old that it dates back before the 17th C. Even my phone's autosuggestion doesn't recognise it. Nice.

Comment: Hold on! "Shall" is alive and kicking, at least in BrE. Expressions like "Shall I pick you up at seven"? and "Shall I come with you"? are commonplace.

Comment: @BillJ Quite so--in AmE, too. But even this is more and more replaced with *should* or with paraphrases like *would you like me to*; and what used to be the dominant use, alternant with *will* in futurives, is evaporating very fast